# Yet another hibernate problem: save to disk work, but cannot wake up

Tags: server, 14.04, hibernate, wakeup

for the past 3 weeks I've been working on setting up an old hp pavillon a1540n with ubuntu server 14.04. Main problem is the hibernate/suspend process. I've done a lot of reading and made great progress thus far, but I feel I reached a point where Google isn't helping anymore.

Right now, pm-hibernate saves to disk correctly, computer stops making sounds, but the screen shows a blinking cursor. After that, no event can wake it up and I have to force shutdown by pressing and holding the power button. On restart however, it loads perfectly and resume where I left. This leaves me thinking that somehow no events can wake it up.

Here is a short list of any effective actions I've done that I can think of:
-Removed graphics card and tv tuner card
-Updated BIOS to 5.07 (no new option for power management though, but it helped)
-Updated driver to nvidia 330 (latest recommended)

Doing basic pm-debugging (basic-pm-debugging.txt#178 on mjmwired dot net), using reboot works fine but using platforms create the same problem as pm-hibernate.

Pastebins:
dmesg: http://pastebin.com/b1KPb4gi
pm-suspend.log: http://pastebin.com/5WAGrFgR
/proc/acpi/wakeup: had to paste it here, askubuntu says I'm not trusty enough to paste more than two links :(

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
HUB0      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:10.0
XVRA      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:04.0
XVRB      S5    *disabled
XVRC      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:02.0
USB0      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0b.0
USB2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0b.1
AZAD      S5    *disabled
MMAC      S5    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
MMCI      S5    *disabled
PS2M      S4    *disabled  pnp:00:07
PS2K      S4    *enabled   pnp:00:08
```

Thanks